# applying for loop

Tags: digital-communications, matlab, fft

I want to apply for loop. Below is my code. I have applied the for loop which is wrong. Here Length(t) is sample numbers. Here I want to create 'for' loop for a sample number 5 in particular. so how to change h in the for loop. Moreover, 'phi_sync' shoud be sample number of 5 and 'phi_acc' shoud be summation from 0 to 5 sample numbers.

```
 fs = 200;
    ts = 1/fs;
    t = 0:ts:1-ts;
    fc = 50;
    S = cos(2*pi*fc*t);                    %%% equation 7.1 noisless
        sigma = 1.8;
    phi_sync =  sigma * randn(1,length(t));   %%%% random variable with gaussian distributed
    phi_acc = sigma * randn(1,length(t));   %%%% random variable with gaussian distributed
    % h = 0;

    for i=1:length(S)
        h = phi_sync + phi_acc(i);
    end
```

---

thanks for your efforts. This is actually algorithm for adding phase noise in a signal. after that i want to add h in the signal S, so i get the phase noise. However when make the new signal using S1 and try to analyze the signal in frequency domain. its showing matrix mistach.

```
S1 = cos(2*pi*fc*t + h);
L = length(S1);
nfft = L*100;           %%%%%% Zero padding
res = fft(S1,nfft)/nfft;     % resize into nfft nr of element % normalize the amplitude
f = fs/2*linspace(0,1,nfft/2+1);
res = res(1:nfft/2+1);
figure, plot(f,abs(res));
% figure, plot(f,angle(res));
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the code and the new comments, it's all explained:

```
fs = 200;
ts = 1/fs;
t = 0:ts:1-ts;
fc = 50;
S = cos(2*pi*fc*t);                    %%% equation 7.1 noisless
sigma = 1.8;

% the length of S and t is 200 sample
phi_sync =  sigma * randn(1,length(t)); 

% to get the 5th sample, 10th sample, 15th sample and so on
phi_sync=phi_sync(1:5:end)

%%%% random variable with gaussian distributed
phi_acc = sigma * randn(1,length(t));   %%%% random variable with gaussian distributed

% new array to get the summation
phi_acc_summ=[];
for i=1:5:length(phi_acc)
    summation=phi_acc(i)+phi_acc(i+1)+phi_acc(i+2)+phi_acc(i+3)+phi_acc(i+4);
    phi_acc_summ=[phi_acc_summ   summation];% append the new value
end

% both phi_sync and phi_acc_summ have 40 samples which is 200/5

% finaly to get the 5th sample you have to simply add 5 in the middle
% of the for loop sine
for i=1:5:length(S)
    h = phi_sync + phi_acc(i);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an if statement to check whether the loop is in the fifth iteration
i.e

```
for i=1:length(S)

   h = phi_sync + phi_acc(i);
    if i==5
       #your code
    end  
end
```

And as far as accessing sample number 5 is concerned use-

phi_sync(5)

and for sum of elements use-

sum(phi_acc)

Comment: Hey thanks Amal. I am not good with loops. How exactly do you mean?

Comment: the i variable gets assigned the value of the current iteration. Now all you need to to do is use an if statement to check whether the value of i is equal to 5, as I have given in my answer. Now '#your code' only gets executed when i is equal to 5

Comment: Forgive me if I misunderstood your question, good luck